# Scrolling to a specific place after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a view page with a button at the bottom of it (haml file):

```
.scroll-here
  = link_to "Button", example_path, id: "my-button"
```

When I press it, the page reloads and I want it to scroll automatically to `.scroll-here` again (but if the page is loaded not because of pressing that button, the focus should be just regular, at the top of the page).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can you differentiate the two when the page loads?

Comment: Well, only by pressing a particular "my-button" button

Comment: So there's no way to know if the button was pressed in the previous page when you load this page? No query string? Different headers? Anything?

Comment: Is it possible to do it with 'onclick' somehow?

Comment: If you're willing to change the behaviour of your "refresh" there's lots of things you can do. How do you "refresh" the page?

Comment: By going to a example_path

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add an id to the element where you want to scroll to, for example:

```
<div id="scrollHereIfButtonIsPressed"></div>
```

Then add the '#scrollHereIfButtonIsPressed' to the URL on the button's action event so that it would scroll to that element when the button is pressed to go to that URL.

ex:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = window.location.href + '?r='+(+new Date())+'#scrollHereIfButtonIsPressed';window.location.reload(true);">
example button
</button>
```

Comment: yes, but it needs an ID for the anchor scrolling to work

Comment: How do I add id="scrollHereIfButtonIsPressed" to " = link_to "Button", example_path, id: "my-button" " ?

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with ruby-on-rails but the following might work:

```
.scroll-here
  = link_to "Button", example_path+"?reload=1", id: "my-button"
```

Use the following jQuery Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if (window.location.href.indexOf("reload=1") >= 0) {
           $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $(".scroll-here").offset().top
           });
     }
 });
```

Comment: I got "Uncaught TypeError: window.location.indexOf is not a function"

Comment: Sorry, forgot the href part @Zelenka

Comment: No, still after reload the focus is on the top of the page